# addEventListener should run constantly a function to get width of an object

Tags: javascript, html

When you click on the rectangle, it shrinks to become a logo. Now I want to unhide the content div when the welcome div is at ~75px width. I can't figure it out how to contantly run a function when you click the mousebutton.

Please help

html

```
<div id="introscreen">
    <div id="welcome"></div>
    <p id="help">Zum beginnen auf Rechteck klicken und halten</p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <header>
        <p id="line">HALLOHALLO</p>
    </header>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var counter = 0;
document.addEventListener("click", function () {
    counter++;
    check();
    console.log(counter);
}, false);

function check() {
    if (counter > 5) {
        document.getElementById("help").style.opacity = '1.00';
    }
}
document.addEventListener("mousedown", fadeAway, false);
document.addEventListener("click", showContent, false);

function fadeAway() {
    document.getElementById("help").style.opacity = '0.00';
    var position = $("#welcome").css("width");
    console.log(position);
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/u93q01q4)**

Comment: Look into `setInterval`

Comment: Please use more words to describe what you're trying to accomplish as it is not clear.  You already have event listeners so your function gets called when mousedown or client events happen.  What else are you trying to accomplish?